# Combining Add to Calendar HOC with Custom Design / Material UI

Tags: reactjs

I am working with the following code to create an [Add to Calendar](https://github.com/jasonleibowitz/react-add-to-calendar-hoc) functionality.

```
const AddToCalendarDropdown = AddToCalendarHOC(Button, Dropdown);
  ...
  <AddToCalendarDropdown
    className={componentStyles}
    linkProps={{
      className: linkStyles,
    }}
    event={event}
  />
```

While that works technically fine, I struggle with the design part. I found the following [MenuList composition](https://material-ui.com/components/menus/#menulist-composition) that would make it quite easy (if it would work).
  The problem I face is how I should be able to add `<MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Item Text</MenuItem>`. I get the items through the HOC, and therefore I struggle to change or adjust these.
  For the Button and the Dropdown, the author gave an option with `const AddToCalendarDropdown = AddToCalendarHOC(Button, Dropdown);`

Comment: I even can't make it work, could you?